# Claymate : TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings

Tags: node.js, bower

Keep getting the same error when trying to run "claymate install" via node cmd ..

Have looked online and rolled back both sass and compass -v  but still no joy

Windows 8.1 O/S

claymate -v 2.0.4

sass -v 3.2.18

compass -v 0.12.4

modular-scale - v 2.0.4

bower -v 1.2.13

Every other script bower dependant works great ..

Jeez, I can even install gumpy through "bower install gumby"

Really at a loss now, have looked on Claymate GH repository and no help there, although a Google search shows it has been an issue of late.

Just wondering if anyone has come by it and how they resolved as I have spent the last 6 hours trying to get a resolution

Many thanks,

J